Bugs in my laptop screen and keyboard. Live bugs, not the software kind
I left my laptop in my attic for a little while, roughly half a year. I decided to pull it out today, and I found tiny white bugs inside the screen that are still alive and are moving around. The laptop is a Thinkpad X220 Tablet, so its an older generation convertible laptop that has a pretty big (and apparently unsealed) air pocket between the LCD and digitizer. There's also bugs in the keyboard but I'm replacing the keyboard because it's faulty, so its not that big of a worry.
The big concern here is how would I even start to lure the bugs out of my screen? I don't want to use a pesticide/gases because that will kill them on the spot, and then the screen would permanently have bugs in it. Why are they even in the screen in the first place? The keyboard makes sense because of all the dust and dead skin, but the screen??
At the moment I'm leaving it in the garage next to a small container with bread crumbs and honey in a brazen attempt to lure them out. I doubt this would work but it's all I can think of.

Have you looked at opening the screen? Looking at some photos it seems almost certain it should be possible and you could then just clean them out.

The bugs re likely going to be unable to be lured out of the device. You will have to remove them yourself by opening the device up.

BTW, you're in good company: RDML Grace Hopper documented a similar issue. https://www.globalapptesting.com/blog/the-worlds-first-computer-bug-global-app-testing

What bugs? Not all of them will be lured out by the same thing, some will have large larvae colonies inside, etc. This is more of a zoology or insectology question than computer one IMO

Honey and crumbs are worthwhile attempts and may yield positive results.  Here are three additional ideas that may help you:

Moisture - those little critters are likely thirsty; try putting a damp sponge and a small cup of water near the laptop
Light - many bugs are attracted to light; try putting a bright light next to the laptop to lure them out
Predators - your bugs are likely near the bottom of the food chain; find critters higher up in the food chain to snarf them up; crickets may find them tasty

